# Orgmode: opening linked file with dedicated application (on mac)

Tags: org-mode, osx

In my org file I've got a link to my `file.docx` file defined like that:

```
[[file:///Users/aaa/file.docx][file.docx]]
```

When I click on the link `file.docx` instead word opening, in the Messages buffer I'm getting this only:

```
Running /Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word /Users/aaa/file.docx...done
```

and nothing else is happening. Word is not called.

I was trying to add lines as below (one at the time):

```
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.docx\\'" . "/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word %s"))
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.docx\\'" . "Microsoft Word.app %s"))
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("docx" . system))
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.docx\\'" . "word %s"))
```

but the final effect was the same :-(

How to successfully tell emacs to open `*.docx` files in Word?

Comment: Org mode has done all it can to open the link with the application specified: I don't know if the problem could be the spaces in the path or some other problem, but it seems that the problem is specific to MacOS. There are MacOS users here who might be able to help, but if you don't get an answer here, you might want to try on a MacOS forum.

Comment: I don't think it's about the spaces. The example I used is literally the same. I keep searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

Correct entry to the list should looks like:

```
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.docx\\'" . "open %s"))
```

Also the link to the file should look like below:

```
[[/Users/aaa/file.docx][file.docx]]
```

rather than with `file:///` preamble. Otherwise it has emacs has a problem with interpreting diacritic characters.

`open` is a macOS command to open files with specific programs.

Answer (score 1):

I am an emacs novice. This worked for me on MacOS 12.6.1, running railwaycat Emacs.

I C-h-v'd org-file-apps and clicked customize.
On that screen I copied exactly what was already there for pdf, but replaced pdf with docx.

[image: A screenshot of the customize buffer]

Clicked file links to docx from org mode now launch word.

If this doesn't work for you then I'd troubleshoot by seeing if emacs can find any external program it links to out of the box. If it can then try creating a link to another file type, to see if it's just word.

I can't stress enough the novice-ness of my knowledge.

Comment: I tried it with no success, but many thanks for sharing your idea.